# Fetch data from mysql to textarea, but if not exist print null

Tags: php, mysql

I made some little translator.
And if word exist in database all is ok. 
But if word didnt exist in database, word isnt printed. 
I add some code to print if result is empty but didnt work.
Any idea why word that not exist in database isnt printed? 
Here is code:

```
<p><form method="post" action="prevedi.php">
<textarea id="prevedi" name="prevedi" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width: 380px;">
<?php 
echo htmlentities($_POST['prevedi']);
?>
</textarea>
<textarea id="prevod" disabled="disabled" name="prevod" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width: 380px; border: 0px;" readonly>
<?
if (isset($_POST['prevedi'])) {
//Kreci
$prevedi = htmlentities($_POST['prevedi']);
$prevedi = explode(" ",$prevedi);
foreach ($prevedi as $word) {
    $slovo = $word[0];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $slovo WHERE srpski='$word'");
    if (!empty($result)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $prevod .= $row['romski']." ";
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
    $prevod .= "".$word." "; 
    }
}
echo $prevod;
//Kraj isset
}
?>
</textarea><br>
<input name="translate" type="submit" value="Translate"/>
</form>
</p>
```

Comment: Try to trim the result before checking if it is empty

Comment: What to trim? Empty null result?

Comment: If you have a word which is an emptyspace it might look empty by it is not, so you may be printing an empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your result is not empty. You should check if `$result` number of rows is > 0

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $prevod .= $row['romski']." ";
     }
}else{
   $prevod .= $word." "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i think you have to initialize $prevod before assigning it the way you did.

$prevod = "";

 if (!empty($result)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $prevod .= $row['romski']." ";
      }`enter code here`
    } 
    else 
    {
    $prevod .= "".$word." "; 
    }
}
echo $prevod;
```